# Web page is not available in Localhost

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a cms application and it was working fine until i made a new page called "session.php" and added a function into that page I then wrote the require once command into the main page of my application and when I run it says "Webpage is not available"...i remove the require once command and my application works again. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

This is the code for session.php

```
<?php session_start();  function message() {

if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) {

$output  = "<div class=\"message\">";
$output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
$output .= "</div>";
return $output;
}}?>
```

This is the code for the page im trying to load

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
<?php find_selected_page(); ?>
<div id="main">
<div id="navigation">
<?php echo navigation($current_subject, $current_page); ?>

<br />
<a href="new_subject.php">+ Add a subject</a>
</div>
<div id="page">
<?php echo message(); ?>
<?php if ($current_subject) { ?>
<h2>Manage Subject</h2>
Menu name: <?php echo $current_subject["menu_name"]; ?>

<?php } elseif ($current_page) { ?>
<h2>Manage Page</h2>
Menu name:<?php echo $current_page["menu_name"]; ?>

<?php } else { ?>
Please select a subject or a page.
<?php }?>

</div>
</div>

<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to basic php programming... I suggest you start monitoring your http servers error log file. That is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines on asking questions. You need to add code samples that illustrate the problem. You can click the "Edit" link below your question in order to do so.

Comment: 1000's of people know how to fix it. **But only if the can see it** show the code for the offending `session.php` and you **might actually get an answer** Nobody here, to my knowledge, is **clairvoyant**

Comment: it could literally be a thousand and one different things going wrong - without sharing your code it is impossible to answer!

Comment: Edit your question - Copy/Paste the code for `session.php` into your questions.

Comment: _knock knock knock_, anybody out there?

Answer (score 1):

The code posted looks oddly-formatted, but I'll venture to say it's not a syntax error.

As others stated, you need to learn the "debugging" process which includes monitoring the error.log file (assuming Apache) and the browser's console (where applicable).

During development, it's a good idea to turn on error reporting to make this a bit easier. Place the following lines at the top of your PHP scripts:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

That won't display 100% of the issues (99.8% give or take), so read up on how to view your server's error log. The answer to your question is hidden in there, I guarantee it.

Comment: Errors usually :) - can you post the code from the page that you're trying to load?

Comment: Yeah but there's hundreds of them just from about 8-9 hours

Comment: That's a problem - let's take the first bite of that elephant! Can you post them? Usually 1 will cause more after once the page "breaks".